# Android, how to get xml resource value from resource id using java

Tags: java, android

In res/ folder I have multilanguage XML files, one for Arabic and the other for English:

```xml
<string name="ram"/>ramallah<string>   
<string name="nablus"/>Nablus<string>  
<string name="jenin"/>Jenin<string> 

<string name="ram"/>رام الله<string>   
<string name="nablus"/>نابلس<string>  
<string name="jenin"/>جنين<string>
```

I define names like:

```
int[] names= {R.string.ram, R.string.nablus, R.string.jenin}
```

I store these values in a database. When I select data I have values like 2131099699,  2131099623, and 21310991231. How can I map these numbers to the names in XML? And how can I get the resource value like ramallah, Nablus, and Jenin from these integer values?

Comment: Why don't you store the names (text) instead of it's resource int values?

Comment: but if you wanna support `multilanguage` in you app this **not** the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the other answers that you need to use getString(/* your id here */).

To support different languages, you just need to create multiple resource files with the strings:

(In Adroid Studio)

1. Right click on res/values folder
2. New -> Values resource file
3. File name: strings.xml
4. Add Locale qualifier
5. Pick your language

Android will automatically pick the appropriate file for the user's locale.

Comment: but my problem is that i know the integer values only , these integer values auto generated by java when i store  int[] names={R.string.ram,R.string.nablus,R.string.jenin} ,i store the integer value in database , so in database i have for name like 2131099699 , 2131099623, 21310991231  , i want to get the related name from xml    getvalue(2131099699)

Comment: So you don't want the value, but rather you want the name of the resource?  So not "ramallah", but "ram"?

Comment: i want the value of strings like  {  Ramallah,Nablus,Jenin }    ,,  i know numbers only 2131099699 , 2131099623, 21310991231   ,,    from these integer numbers how to return or get Ramallah , nablus , jenin

Comment: these numbers stored in database , and i want to search by name , when i get data from database i got numbers 2131099699 , 2131099623, 21310991231  ,  how to map these numbers to the real names Ramallah,Nablus,jenin

Comment: If you want the value, then the answers provided are correct.  The getString(int) method will return the String value for the id you passed in.  Usually you would pass in the resource by reference, but since you have the id already, just pass that in directly.  See the documentation for [Context.getString(@StringRes int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Well, that's likely because the resource id has changed since you stored that value in the DB (since I assume this is not the same across multiple app compilations).  If you need multi-language support, use the locale method I provided in my answer.  That's the correct way to provide support for multiple languages.

Comment: thank you for your help , i think this is the problem , resource id changed when stored in DB , i will try using locale method ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving resource ids in that way, you can save to database the resource name:

```
String[] names = {"ram", "nablus", "jenin"};
```

Then you can access the resource value in this way:

```
int stringId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nameStored, "string", context.getPackageName());
String stringValue = "default string";
if (stringId != 0) {
   stringValue = context.getResources().getString(stringId);
}
```

Comment: i only know the integer values and don't know the id   , like these values 2131099699 , 2131099623, 21310991231 , how to refer these values to R.string

Comment: I updated the answer, check if that is what you need

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler , i will try your answer , but i was looking for storing the id , and get resource value from that id

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by storing in DB NAMES like

```
String[] Names = {this.getResources().getString(R.string.ram),
this.getResources().getString(R.string.nablus),
this.getResources().getString(R.string.jenin)}
```

by this way , i keep using multi language with one database and same table